# string vector printed into int?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm currently doing an activity w/ vectors and I stumbled upon this question.

A procedure that takes an array variable of size 4 by 4. 
The array variable should be string type.
The contents of the array are illustrated below.

The contents:

```
aa  ab  ac  ad
ba  bb  bc  bd
ca  cb  empty   cd
da  db  dc  dd
```

This is what your procedure should do, gets the board and displays to the user as below,

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  empty   12
13  14  15  16
```

I managed to print it out as strings but I have no idea on how to turn it into int after printing.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <vector> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    vector<vector<string> > thirdQuiz
    { 
        { "aa", "ab", "ac", "ad" }, 
        { "ba", "bb", "bc", "bd" }, 
        { "ca", "cb", "empty", "cd" },
        { "da", "db", "dc", "dd" },  
    };

    // Displaying the 2D vector   
    for (int i = 0; i < thirdQuiz.size(); i++) 
    { 
        for (int j = 0; j < thirdQuiz[i].size(); j++)
        {
            cout << thirdQuiz[i][j] << " "; 
        } 
        cout << endl; 
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What are the rules? Print the index of the element or `"empty"` when `thirdQuiz[i][j]` equals `"empty"`?

Comment: Just convert strings to numbers with the base 4 and add 1. If it is not convertible, leave the original string.

Comment: I'm assuming index (it wasn't clearly stated) because the "empty" string will be shuffled moving from an index to another. Thanks

Comment: The 'index' is just `4*i + j + 1`, simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume right, you need to display the index. Then several possibilities come around.
One is:

1. Multiply the outer index with the inner size and add the inner counter:
   `auto count = i * thirdQuiz[i].size() + j + 1;` But be aware this only works if the inner vectors all have the same size.
2. Then you have to check if the value is empty then print "empty" or the number.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < thirdQuiz.size(); i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < thirdQuiz[i].size(); j++) {
            if(!thirdQuiz[i][j].empty() && thirdQuiz[i][j] != "empty"){
                std::cout << i * thirdQuiz[i].size() + j + 1 << " ";
                continue;
            }
            std::cout << "empty" << " "; 
        } 
        std::cout << endl; 
    }
```

A more robust way would be to just count all entries in your vectors:

```
    size_t count{};
    for (auto const& inner_vec: thirdQuiz) { 
        for (auto const& string_val: inner_vec) {
            ++count;
            if(!string_val.empty() && string_val != "empty"){
                std::cout << count << " ";
                continue;
            }
            std::cout << "empty" << " "; 
        } 
        std::cout << endl; 
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, can you please explain this line to me and how it actually displays the index. Thanks ```i * thirdQuiz[i].size() + j + 1```

Comment: Hi, `i` counts the rows you handled till now (note i starts at 0) and `thirdQuiz[i].size()` is the size of one row. Therefore `i*thirdQuiz[i].size()` is the count of all handled fields. Adding `j + 1`gives you the element count.